# Why I get error "Could not find MyLibrarry.apk!"

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-library, library-project

I have an android project that has a reference to project `MyLibrary`. I have checked `Is Library` for project `MyLibrary` and build it without error.

I have added `MyLibrary` to `Main Project` in Properties->android->Library and Java Build Path in Projects tab. I can build the `Main Project` completely.

[image]

[image]

But when I launch the `Main Project` I get this error:

```
[2012-11-18 15:18:08 - MyLibrary] Could not find MyLibrary.apk!
```

I have cleaned the projects and studied the following links but I have this error yet.

[Could not find Library.apk!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

[Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

[Could not find ****.apk + android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273129/could-not-find-apk-android)

Why and how can I solve it?

I should mention that when I open Properties->android->Library for `Main Project` I see that the inserted library has a red cross.

Is it related to slash `/` and backslash `\` in the path of reference in the pictures?

[image]

Comment: "Library" not "Librarry" (not that it makes any difference here, but just a note :)

Comment: 1. You must use relative path reference the library project. 2. You may need import the library project into Eclipse under same workspace as the dependant project. More details in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200751/eclipse-will-not-recognize-project-as-library-actionbarsherlock-viewpagerindica/10219498#10219498).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to yorkw. The `Main Project` was in drive D:... and `MyLibrary` was in C:.... I put `MyLibrary` in folder where `Main Project` was and the problem solved.