# Could not find ****.apk error in Android

Tags: android

When I am trying to run my Android application in Eclipse I am getting "Could not find ****.apk!" error. Till today my application was running without any problem. Not able to find out why this error is coming.

Any help is appreciated.

Rohan.

Comment: I think I updated ADT plugin..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273129/could-not-find-apk-android

Comment: this question is already asked many times , have you tried the solutions?
You can find Related Questions on Right side of the Screen

Comment: Yes..I tried the solutions..But its not working for me. my .classpath file contents-

Comment: 3rd line is - <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>

Comment: Other Projects in Workspace are Running or No project is running>

Comment: Update your Eclipse again ,might be the partial solution of the problem

Comment: I have the same problem since today. Never encountered this until I updated the adt plugin to v 22.0.1 a few hours ago

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these steps; this might help you out:

Go to Project->Properties

Select Android from left-hand side list

Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox

if its not work try this-
deleting the R.Java file in /Gen folder and then clean your project.

Comment: @henry:glad to help you.Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android SDK Build-tools installed?

I encountered the same problem, after upgrading the Eclipse adt plugin to v 22.0.1. I did not had the build-tools installed before, but upgrading the SDK tools and installing the build tool fixed it for me.